# Зачем использовать метод on() при назначении событий в джейквери?

Tags: jquery

Какие преимущества дает назначение событий через универсальный метод `on()` перед назначением событий, например, методами `click()`, `hover()`, `keydown()`?

Answer (score 3):

Данный метод не дает никаких преимуществ, просто потому, что все перечисленные [методы внутри используют этот метод](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/event/alias.js#L10):

```
jQuery.each( ( "blur focus focusin focusout resize scroll click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup contextmenu" ).split( " " ),
    function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
} );
```

Правда, можно отметить, что при создании используются не все параметры метода `on`. Подробнее прочитать о данном методе можно в [справке](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Не используется параметр *selector*, позволяющий указать от какого из вложенных элементов ловить событие. Если `null` или пропущен, события будут ловиться, только на элементах из набора.

Для сравнения:

Одинаковое поведение

```
$(selector).click(function(){...});
$(selector).on('click',null,function(){...});
```

Все еще одинаковое поведение

```
$('parent child').click(function(){...});
$('parent child').on('click',null,function(){...});
```

Поведение будет отличаться, так как сам обработчик навешан на родителя, поэтому не важно в какой момент был добавлен элемент *child* по которому кликнули.

```
$('parent').on('click','child',function(){...});
```

Comment: пишут, что click(), hover().. не навесится на динамически созданные элементы, а on() - навесится

Comment: @Dimon, на самом деле нет. Прочитай последние два абзаца в ответе.

Comment: @Dimon, добавил примеры, в каком случае будет отличаться поведение.

Comment: *"Не дает никаких преимуществ ... кроме ... и кроме ... и кроме"* :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, там только одно кроме :-) так что не надо тут :-)

Answer (score 2):

Например есть структура

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

задача - ловить клики на элементы

можно просто

```
$('.elem').click(f)
```

но тогда создается МНОГО хендлеров

вместо этого лучше сделать вот так

```
$('#container').on('click', '.elem', f)
```

в этом случае хендлер создается только один
допольнительно ловиться добавленные ПОСЛЕ подключения хендлера элементы, типа live